# How to check a text file for a long string with symbols in bash and insert if not found?

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
STRING="INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry $HostMachineIP:5000'"

FILE=/etc/sysconfig/docker

if [ ! -z $(grep [["$STRING"]] "$FILE") ]
then
    :
else
    echo $STRING >> $FILE
fi
```

This isn't working, it echos the string every time in the file and it should only do it if it's not found, but then I'm left with

```
INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry 192.168.0.1:5000'
INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry 192.168.0.1:5000'
INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry 192.168.0.1:5000'
INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry 192.168.0.1:5000'
INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry 192.168.0.1:5000'
INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry 192.168.0.1:5000'
```

The script is ran a few times a day.

What am I over looking here?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: "This isn't working". What do you expect? What is the input, what output to you expect?

Comment: I specified it echoes it every time regardless if it's in there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional statement is a bit wonky, give this a try:

```
STRING="INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry $HostMachineIP:5000'"

FILE=/etc/sysconfig/docker

if ! grep -qe "$STRING" "$FILE"
then
    echo $STRING >> $FILE
fi
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

[`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) has this option:

> -v, --invert-match
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is specified by POSIX .)